# How to make negative values ​red and positive values ​green in treemap plotly with python, and how to change according to date and time data

Tags: colors, plotly, treemap, negative-number, timeserieschart

my data has date and time and percentage i want to resize with negative values ​​to red and positive values ​​to blue , this is my data:

[image]

I want every attribute in the "percentage" column with a negative value to be red and a positive value to be Green
enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsnVH.png)

Comment: What is your problem, did you try to solve it?

Comment: can you post your data as formatted text using `df.head(10).to_dict()` ? also can you show either the documentation you've looked through or the code you've tried to solve the problem (even if it doesn't work)? people will be more likely to help if your problem is reproducible and you show you've made a good faith effort

Comment: I have tried many ways but it still seems to be wrong somewhere

Comment: fig = px.treemap(data, path=[px.Constant('all'),'Stablecoin','Name','percentage'],values='Value_USDT')
fig.update_traces(textinfo = "label",textposition="middle center",hovertemplate='labels=%{label}<br>value=%{value}<extra></extra>')
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(
    colors=data['percentage'],
    colorscale=colorscale,
    cmax = np.max(data['percentage'].astype(int)),
    cmin=np.min(data['percentage'].astype(int)),
    cmid=np.mean(data['percentage'].astype(int)),
    showscale=True
))
fig.update_layout(width=1400, height=550)
fig.show()

Comment: this is my code for treemap plotly